# kv file: Invalid data after declaration

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm on python 3.6.5 on win8. I'm following this (https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html ) tutorial. This is the situation: 
I have **main.py**:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class PongGame(Widget):
    pass


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

and **pong.kv**:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<PongGame>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
```

When I open main.py, I get the following error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Lorenzo\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-07-05_3.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSCv.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
  PongApp().run()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 801, in run
  self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 598, in load_kv
  root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
  return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 350, in load_string
  parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 392, in __init__
  self.parse(content)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 501, in parse
  objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 575, in parse_level
 'Invalid data after declaration')
kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "C:\Users\Lorenzo\Documents\app-kivy\pong.kv", line 1:
 ...
       1:ï»¿#:kivy 1.10.1
       2:
       3:PongGame:
 ...
 Invalid data after declaration
```

I haven't found solutions on stack and nowhere.

Can you please help me?

EDIT: I solved. The problem was the utf8 encoding [You can see that here: "(...) 1:ï»¿#:kivy 1.10.1 (...)" ]. So I saved my kv file using ANSI encoding and it works

Comment: I solved. The problem was the utf8 encoding [You can see that here: "(...) 1:ï»¿#:kivy 1.10.1 (...)" ]. 
So I saved my kv file using ANSI encoding and it works.

Comment: Do not add [SOLVED] the title of your question to indicate that it solved your problem, so it is not done in SO, what you should do is create an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved. The problem was the utf8 encoding [You can see that here: "(...) 1:ï»¿#:kivy 1.10.1 (...)" ]. So I saved my kv file using ANSI encoding and it works

Comment: Wow I'd never guessed this, why can't it read standard Unicode encoding? Thanks! Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too. This is not exactly your case but it might be helpful for you or somebody else. In my case the error happened because of data declaration was AFTER rule declaration.

Wrong:

```
top_menu: top_menu
TopMenu:
    id: top_menu

screen_manager: screen_manager
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    transition:
        SlideTransition(direction='down')
    Screen:
        name: 'MainPageScreen'  
        MainPageScreen
    Screen:
        name: 'MenuScreen'  
        MenuScreen
```

Right:

```
top_menu: top_menu
screen_manager: screen_manager

TopMenu:
    id: top_menu

ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    transition:
        SlideTransition(direction='down')
    Screen:
        name: 'MainPageScreen'
        MainPageScreen
    Screen:
        name: 'MenuScreen'
        MenuScreen
```

It seems that because of the colon ":" in line "x = content.split(':', 1)" python parses the line "screen_manager: screen_manager" as a part of a rule declaration. Here is a snippet from python\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py (ln 563):

```
        # Level finished
        if count < indent:
            return objects, lines[i - 1:]

        # Current level, create an object
        elif count == indent:
            x = content.split(':', 1)
            if not len(x[0]):
                raise ParserException(self, ln, 'Identifier missing')
            if (len(x) == 2 and len(x[1]) and
                    not x[1].lstrip().startswith('#')):
                raise ParserException(self, ln,
                                      'Invalid data after declaration')
```